# She is saving the money, She (is buying/is going to buy) a new computer next week... Which one?

Tags: future-tense

Is saving money consider as an intention or as an arrangment ? 
Since i turned the intention into an action and started saving . But i can't really say that it is an arrangment either

It was a question in my quiz:
By arrangments i mean using present continous 
intention : going to

Comment: I think the word "arrangement" has some special meaning for you which is different from the standard definition.  Could you add more context?  Why is it important whether it is an "intention" or an "arrangement"?  Does this change the grammar in any significant way?

Answer (score 2):

"**Saving money**" is an in-action arrangement, not a planned one. The second part can either be an intention "*is going to buy*" or an arrangement "*is buying*". *([read here](http://www.really-learn-english.com/intentions-arrangements-future.html))*

An "**arrangement**" is something planned or arranged *(for now or the future)*.